# Как в js остановить асинхронную функцию

Tags: javascript, функции

У меня есть код:

```
async function parse(stop) {
  let i = await eel.parse1_rest()(); // Просто получение списка
  let l = [];
  for (let t of i) {
    rest = await eel.parse1_rest(t)();
    l.push(rest);
  }
  document.getElementById("butt_1").onclick = parse;
```

мой HTML

```html
<button id="butt_1">Получить данные</button>
<button id="butt_2">Остановить</button>
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Остановить" моя функция останавливалась.

Comment: Чтобы не плодить глобальных переменных, можно при нажатии на кнопку остановки делать её неактивной, а в цикле функции проверять активность кнопки и прерывать цикл, если кнопка неактивна.

Comment: а как мне потом достать значение переменной l

Comment: Если вам нужно потом опять начать с того же места, укажите это в вопросе. Пока читается так, что нужно просто оборвать исполнение.

Comment: В коде закрывающей фигурной скобки не хватает, и хз где она должна быть (наверное после блока `for`, но я не стал дописывать наугад) - поправь сам, пожалуйста, вместе с дополнением про доступ к значению `l`. Ну и заголовок тогда уж "остановить"►"приостановить", а то противоречие получается.